# Is there a way to join 2 records from same table in SQL

Tags: sql, join

Already found!!!

```
join ItemUom k on k.Item = Item.Oid and k.ItemUomId = 'Krat'    
etc ...
```

Is there a way to join/link some fields of 2 different records of same table?
See picture for example of data structure. Can I give the results of the joins a name, so I can get fields from those?

I want something like:

```
select  Item.ItemId, 
        Item.Description,
        ItemUom'Krat'.ItemUomId,
        ItemUom'Krat'.ContentQty,
        ItemUom'Stuks'.ItemUomId,
        ItemUom'Stuks'.ContentQty,
from Item
join ItemUom 'Krat' on ItemUom.Item = Item.Oid and ItemUomId = 'Krat' 
join ItemUom 'Stuks' on ItemUom.Item = Item.Oid and ItemUomId = 'Stuks'
```

[image: Example of data structure]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use single quotes for aliases.  But your query has many other issues.

If I understand correctly, you want to `join` the tables and can then use conditional aggregation for the "pivoting" that you want to do.

I think this does what you want:

```
select i.ItemId, i.Description,
       max(case when iu.ItemUomId = 'Krat' then iu.ItemUomId end),
       max(case when iu.ItemUomId = 'Krat' then iu.ContentQty end),
       max(case when iu.ItemUomId = 'Stuks' then iu.ItemUomId end),
       max(case when iu.ItemUomId = 'Stuks' then iu.ContentQty end)
from ItemUom iu join
     Item ik
     on iu.Item = i.Oid 
group by i.ItemId, i.Description
```

EDIT:

Actually, the following produces the same output, but I think it is the approach you are trying to take:

```
select i.ItemId, i.Description,
       ik.ItemUomId, ik.ContentQty,
       ist.ItemUomId, ist.ContentQty
from Item i join
     ItemUom ik
     on ik.Item = i.Oid and
        ik.ItemUomId = 'Krat' join
      ItemUom ist
      on ist.Item = i.Oid and 
         ist.ItemUomId = 'Stuks';
```

Note the use of table aliases.  And single quotes are ONLY used for strings, not for column or table aliases.